# Android Studio Eclipse Import

Tags: android, eclipse, import, android-studio

Android Studio 0.4 is supposed to be able to convert and import eclipse projects instead of the prior process of exporting from eclipse (which never worked for me even for simple projects).  I'm getting this error when I try to import a simple project in Studio 0.4:

```
* Project x:C:\proj\x:
No project.project file found in C:\proj\x
```

Has anyone had success with the new studio import?

Comment: have you tried file-->import Project

Comment: That's how you get to the error I'm seeing.  I'm confused about "project.project", I obviously have the eclipse .project and changing that to project.project causes a different import system.  I'm assuming it's yet another adoption blocking bug in the studio system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is a typo.  It should be project.properties.  It was missing in my repo.  I submitted a issue for them to fix the typo.

Answer (score 0):

If you delete the project.properties file from Eclipse, Android Studio will be able to import your project correctly.